# Slim Framework and Twig templating engine

Tags: php, twig, slim

Hello so I have a simple code here that will render `home.html` using slim framework and twig. Here's the codes:

In my index.php file:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim([
        'debug' => true,
        'templates.path' => 'app/views'
    ]);

$app->view = new \Slim\Views\Twig();
$app->view->setTemplatesDirectory("app/views");

$view = $app->view();
$view->parserOptions = ['debug' => true];
$view->parserExtensions = [new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension()];

$app->get('/home', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('home.html');
});

$app->run();
```

Here is the base.html template:
[image]

And my home.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
 Some content here
{% endblock %}
```

My question is, since the only rendered part is the `home.html`, what if I want some data loaded in my base template? Like this..
[image]

So that I won't have to repeat it on every page I render. Is that possible on a base template? Thank you in advance.

Also, [this](https://imron02.wordpress.com/2015/04/20/install-twig-views-template-in-slim-framework/) is what I followed to install twig in slim.

Comment: Will you load this data on every page/route?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30031597/3893182). There the answerer say "write a [Twig custom function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions)" to load dynamically data in your views.

So you would be able to write your own PHP, can inject your DB and use this along with that templating engine.

Comment: You are right, but I can't make my own functions using slim and twig :/

Comment: I mean, I don't know how.. I followed the docs but I really don't know how to properly do it..

Comment: This is what I followed to install views on slim https://imron02.wordpress.com/2015/04/20/install-twig-views-template-in-slim-framework/

Comment: Slim itself has [own twig functions](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Views/blob/master/TwigExtension.php) - They are added via function [parserExtensions](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Views#twig-1)