# Base template Twig

Tags: templates, twig, slim

I have multiple templates that extends my `base` template. My question is, is it possible for a base template to carry out data from database? I am using slim framework btw. This is how I render templates with slim:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('index.html');
});
```

Now, what I am trying to say looks like this:
[image]

As you can see in the `div loadedData`, the data comes from the database. But the question is, it is the `base template`. How can it get the data like that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slim Framework and Twig templating engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108084/slim-framework-and-twig-templating-engine)

Comment: @copynpaste that is also OP's question, not very helpful in this situation.

Comment: Genius i just flagged it, if I ask same question 2 times it IS just a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is registering a global variable in the templates so even the base template can access it without you having to manually paste it every time.

#### Custom middleware

You will need to write your own (very simple) middleware. It would look something like this:

```
class GlobalTwigVars extends \Slim\Middleware
{
    public function call()
    {
        $conn = ???; // somehow get your database connection
        $this->app->view['my_data'] = $conn->query(...)->fetchAll();
        $this->next->call(); // VERY IMPORTANT
    }
}
```

This middleware will be called sometime after the request starts and before your controller is executed. It adds a global variable `my_data` which contains your query result ([the `Twig` class supports `ArrayAccess` for setting global variables](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View/blob/master/src/Twig.php)).

#### Register the middleware with Slim

This is very simple, just add this somewhere in your initialization file:

```
$app = new Slim\Slim;
// blah blah
$app->add(new GlobalTwigVars);

$app->get('/something', function() { /* ... */ });
```

#### Inside your template

Now all you have to do is traverse the data in your template. Unlike what you did in your screenshot, you need to use Twig syntax, not raw PHP. For example:

```
<ul>
    {% for row in my_data %}
    <li>{{ row.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

**Note**: this method will execute your query on every single request, which may not be what you want. Feel free to add some conditional logic inside the middleware to avoid unnecessary queries.